# jQuery range slider - strange behavior (wrong values)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Im trying to use uiSlider to define hourrange.
http://marcneuwirth.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/timeslider3.html

Slider handles behave strangely - when moving right slider, it changes value correctly (or not quite), but when leaved, and moved left handle - value of right handle changes. Same thing happends in other direction.
Also moving one handle left and right shows strange changes in values.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Can you recreate your logic in jsfiddle, so it would be easier to see your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberek/a5hRe/
Just forgot how jsfiddle is great :D

Comment: I cannot see the problem in Chrome, which browser are you trying?

Comment: MEanwhile I have found some solution... $("#slider").slider("values", 0) is a problem, and ui.values[0] should be used, but I cannot access it from slideTime function :/

Comment: Chrome also. Move left slider to 8:55, then slide right handle in left dirrection - start time from 8:55 will change to 9:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have played a bit with your jsfiddle and modified a bit your slideTime function

http://jsfiddle.net/a5hRe/6/

```
val0 = ui != undefined ? ui.values[0] : 480,
val1 = ui != undefined ? ui.values[1] : 1080
```

You may want to refactor this code, but it looks like now it is working fine.

Comment: Never thought of that... Nice one, thanks :). 
Could You just give me a small tip. how to set those values once (like in variable) so I dont have to change them separatly in this function, and in slider callout?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was off for a weekend. Probably you found out but I can suggest this way: inside your callback function you can access options of your slider but using following javascript: $("#slider").data("slider").options.min and $("#slider").data("slider").options.max (in your case first would be 480 and second 1080)
Please mark as answer if that helps.